# Should I use simple past or present perfect in the following sentence?

Tags: verbs, tenses

In the sentence: "I (have) never memorized vocabulary - I (have) simply read many books"

I had looked at grammar websites and the suggested duplicates, but didn't find an answer.

Which verb tense should I use?

Comment: "I never memorized English vocabulary; I simply have read many books," is quite clear, with the "have" in the second clause making it clear that you intend to say "red" instead of "reed" (assuming that is your intention, of course).

Comment: This question cannot be answered meaningfully as it stands: perfect constructions are used to establish temporal reference **relative to the discourse context**, and there is no context here.

Comment: StoneyB - How would I answer the following question "How did you learn English vocabulary"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither is *wrong* per se...like so many issues regarding verb tenses, it just depends on what you are trying to communicate.

Because the action of (doing things that would result in memorizing vocabulary) is presumably ongoing, I would use a perfect tense: "I have never memorized vocabulary..." My assumption here is that there has been an ongoing process over many years that might continue to extend into the future. In other words, you are describing *the way that you have been behaving and anticipate you will continue to behave*. In that case, the perfect tense is appropriate. If, by contrast, you are describing a very specific period of time in the past that is now over, then use the simple past: "I never memorized vocabulary [in grade school]..."

The same analysis pertains to the second half of the sentence. There is an argument to me made that "have read," "read [past]" and "read [present]" *could* all be valid in this scenario. However, I would justify the use of the perfect tense here because: (1) it provides parallelism with the first half of the sentence; (2) it ensures clarity of tense, since the particular word "read" changes its pronunciation but not its spelling for past vs. present; and (3) it implies that there has been much reading in the past and that you anticipate reading more in the future, which is presumably correct for someone who is speaking this sentence.